# What is the purpose of "Process name" in RIP for IPv6 on Cisco Routers

Tags: cisco, ipv6, rip

I was going through Cisco documentation to configure RIP for IPv6. One of the steps says

> Enables the specified IPv6 RIP routing process on an interface.

But they do not go into detail about this process. Nothing turned out on google search as well. All the examples I found uses the same process name on all the interfaces and also on the different router.

What I am trying to understand is, under what scenario would you choose different process (process names) for different interfaces on the same router and other routers on the same network?

Comment: If you have more than one instance ip RIP for IPv6 (or any other protocol), the name is used to identify a particular instance.

Comment: If the answer helped you please consider accepting it so this question can be closed, thank you.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to run more than one instance of RIPng on a single router.

You can run a different process on different interfaces and you can also run multiple processes on the same interface.

One reason to do this may be that you want tighter control of updates between two interfaces.  You can run separate processes on each interface and use route-maps to control redistribution between the two processes.

Another reason may be that you want to completely segregate routing traffic between two sets of interfaces.  If interfaces 1 & 2 are in one process and interfaces 3 and 4 are in the other process.  The router will exchange routing information between interfaces 1 and 2.  It will also exchange routing information between interfaces 3 and 4.  It will not exchange routing information from 1 and 2 with 3 and 4 or vice versa.  This does not provide data plane segregation (as with VRF), just control of routing.  If traffic arrives in on interface 1 and it is destined for interface 3 it will be routed out of that interface as there is single routing table.

The process names are only locally significant and do not need to match between routers.  If you need to run multiple processes on the same interface you must change the UDP port number for one of the processes as there is no process identifier in the update.  If you run both processes on the same port number the routing information will be merged on the receiving router.